# Using POST with React Fetch returns an empty object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a very simple backend server built in Node/Express that accepts a post request via

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/auth/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

When I send a POST to this via Postman with key/value in the body it returns in Postman as expected and I can see in my NodeJS console that the exchange is happening via the `console.log`. However, when I do the same thing with React, it just logs an empty object.

This is my React:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { email } = this.state;

  fetch('/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    body: {
      "email": email
    }
  });

  console.log("EMAIL", email)
}
```

I have state being updated as the user types in their email and when they click the submit button it triggers this `handleSubmit()`.

However the output is a lackluster empty `{}`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here that the API wouldn't log the state? React logs the data getting posted to the API and it looks valid.

**Update**

Here is the code that is updating the state:

```
 handleChange(e) {
   const email = e.target.value;

   this.setState({
     email,
   });
 }
```

Update, I wasn't using `.then()` to return the data hence why I was getting an empty object.

Comment: can you post your setState function which changes the email?

Comment: fetch returns a promise and you need to call then() on it.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri updated my post at the bottom of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fetch('/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    body: {
      "email": email
    }
  }).then(res => console.log(res));
```

you need use .then()

Comment: This was it. Thank you! I am new to using fetch for POST requests. It's been all `get` requests up until now. It makes total sense that my code was incomplete without the `.then()`